# One primary key in one table linked to two foreign keys in two different tables?

Tags: mysql

How to point two table `foreign key` to references same `primary key` in other table?
My database sample structure is like,

```
table1 - user(id (pk),name)
table2 - question(id (fk),type)
table2 - choice(id (fk),choice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Try like this

```
CREATE TABLE `user`
(
id int NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id )
);

CREATE TABLE question
(
id int NOT NULL,
type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES `user`(id)
);

CREATE TABLE choice
(
id int NOT NULL,
choice varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES `user`(id)
);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e50b9/1)**